# Global shared variable vue.js using vue-cli-3

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I have a base.scss under src/style/base.scss. This file has imports for all variables and mixins.

When I serve my project using vue-cli-3 it says unknown variable $black.

To solve it, I referred this https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders and added

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: '@import "@/style/base.scss";'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to my vue.config.js

It solved the previous issue but my icons imported and used via v-icon from

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons'>
```

doesn't get resolved(text is displayed instead of icons) and even vuetify styles imported using

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

doesn't work.

How do I make the vuetify and icons import work?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to get Vuetify and icons import work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. It was getting imported but reset.css was getting loaded after the vuetify which in turn was overriding the styles.

Called reset.css in the beginning of index.html.